# Using ChangeDetectionStrategy in Angular 6, need to add conditional class on child element (ng-class)

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

I have a parent component

```
export class ItemsComponent implements OnInit {
    itemList: any;
    constructor(private itemService:ItemService) {}
    ngOnInit() {
         this.itemService.getJsonData()
        .subscribe(response => {             
            this.itemList = response;           
         }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
         });
    }
    selectCheckItemParent(event): void{
        for(var counter=0; counter<this.itemList.length;counter++){
            if(this.itemList[counter].itemId==event.target.dataset.cid){
                this.itemList[counter].isSelected   =   event.target.checked;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And a Child Component

```
export class ListViewComponent implements OnInit {  
    @Input() itemList : Item[];
    @Output() selectCheckItemParent = new EventEmitter<string,string>();
    constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
    get runChangeDetection() {
        console.log('ListView - Checking the view');
        return true;
    }
    selectCheckThisItem(event, itemSelected){
        this.selectCheckItemParent.emit(event);
    }
}
```

With HTML

```
<li *ngFor="let item of itemList;" >
    <input attr.data-cid="{{item.cid}}" (change)="selectCheckThisItem($event, item)" type="checkbox"  class="checkbox-custom"  #isSelected  ng-class="{ item.isSelected == true : 'checked'}" /> 
    <span class="row items-div" ng-class="{ item.isSelected==true : 'selectedItem' }">
        {{item.isSelected}}
    </span>
</li>
```

Now this span inside the li tag shows true/false when any change is detected but when isSelected is true the ng-class should add "selectedItem" class, which is not happening.

Answer (score 1):

When passing in an object to ngClass, the **keys** are the classes you want to add. The **values** are truthy or falsy expressions which will add or remove that class.

The ngClass directive should be written in camelCase, and should be surrounded by square brackets, which tell Angular to evaluate the value as a template expression.

So your expression should look like this:

```
<span [ngClass]="{ selectedItem: item.isSelected }">
```